# How is this differential equation simplified? Is $\frac{d(v_a + v_b)}{dt} = \frac{dv_a}{dt} + \frac{dv_b}{dt}$ with $v_a$ and $v_b$ functions of $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can this equation

$$
(v_i - v_1)g_1 - C_1\frac{dv_1}{dt}+C_2\frac{d(v_o - v_1)}{dt} = 0
$$

be simplified to this?

$$
v_i g_1 = g_1 v_1 + (C_1 + C_2)\frac{dv_1}{dt} - C_2\frac{dv_o}{dt} 
$$

I see how to simplify it if

$$
\frac{d(v_o - v_1)}{dt} = \frac{dv_o}{dt} - \frac{dv_1}{dt}
$$

but is this true in general?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem),
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The differential operator is linear.

Comment: Hi! Yes, please typeset your mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Doing so will help keep your answer from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, experienced users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. ¶ For example, `$\frac{d(v_o-v_1)}{dt}$` yields $\frac{d(v_o-v_1)}{dt}$ and `$(v_i-v_1)g_1 = v_ig_1-v_1g_1$` yields $(v_i-v_1)g_1 = v_ig_1-v_1g_1$.

Comment: I corrected the title.

Comment: @whpowell96 The title is relevant to the question because his confusion is cleared up if differentiation is a linear operator (as later confirmed by JMoravitz). Sorry, OP, I'd probably have left the second part of the title in there, and just MathJaxed it up. :-)

Comment: I replaced the pictures by MathJax.

Comment: If $F$ and $G$ are differentiable, then so is $aF + bG$ for any constants $a$ and $b$, and it is true that $(aF+bG)' = aF' + bG'$. As @JMoravitz says, the differential operator is linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v_0$ and $v_1$ are functions (of $t$) and if $v_i = v_1$ (a typo?) then the property in question is true in general. Derivatives have this property.

Comment: Yes, $v_x$ are all functions. And I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether this:
$$\dfrac{d(v_o - v_i)}{dt} =\dfrac{d}{dt}v_o - \dfrac{d}{dt}v_i$$
then yes, it is true.

---

Looking at it step-by-step you have:
$$\dfrac{d(v_o - v_i)}{dt}$$
so we understand that the expression $(v_o - v_i)$ is differentiated with respect to $t$
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}(v_o - v_i)$$
and this $d/dt$ can be distributed to each term in the same way as you mentioned in your question
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}v_o - \dfrac{d}{dt}v_i$$

Answer (score 0):

I know this will be unpopular, but you can separate differentiation in general from differentiation with respect to something, as a derivative is merely a ratio of differentials.

Let's start with the expression $x - y$.  To differentiate, you simply perform the differential operator (without respect to anything), which yields:

$$d(x - y) = dx - dy$$

You can freely divide any expression by any non-zero value.  $dt$ is such a value, so you can freely divide both sides by $dt$:

$$\frac{d(x - y)}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} - \frac{dy}{dt}$$

Comment: This is unsettling.  Even if it may not be strictly wrong, in general settings and contexts most people are taught not to treat these as numbers.  It would be far more comforting to me to see this written as $\frac{d}{dt}$ as the differential operator and noting that $\frac{d}{dt}[x-y] = \frac{d}{dt}[x] - \frac{d}{dt}[y]$ rather than talking about "dividing by $dt$."

Comment: It's only "merely" a ratio of differentials in non-standard analysis, no?